# How to pass data from parent component to child component and navigate to child page in Angular?

Tags: angular, routes

I have created Parent and child component and I'm trying to pass data from parent to child and navigate to child page. but data is not getting passed when I navigate to child page. Data is getting passed when I display the child component in the same page. Bellow I have added the code. It works if I remove `this.router.navigate(['/single-track']);` line. But I want it should navigate to other page and display there.

Parent.html

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card" *ngFor="let track of trackList">
                <div class="name">{{track.productName}}</div>
                <div class="tracklink">
                    <audio controls>
                        <source src="{{track.imageUrl}}" type="audio/mpeg">
                    </audio>
                </div>
                <div><span (click)="TrackPage(track)"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<app-main-track-page [currentTrack] = "currentTrack" *ngIf="value"></app-main-track-page>
```

Parent.ts

```
import { GetTrackService } from '../get-track.service';
import { track } from '../track';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  trackList: track[];
  currentTrack:track;
  value:boolean = false;

  constructor(private getdata: GetTrackService, private router:Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getdata.getTrack().subscribe(
      data => this.trackList = data
    );
  }

  TrackPage(track:track):void{
    this.currentTrack = track;
    console.log("Home track: ", this.currentTrack)
    this.value = true;
    this.router.navigate(['/child']);
  }
}
```

Child.html

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="name">{{currentTrack.productName}}</div>
                <div class="tracklink">
                    <audio controls>
                        <source src="{{currentTrack.imageUrl}}" type="audio/mpeg">
                    </audio>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Child.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-track-page',
  templateUrl: './main-track-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-track-page.component.css']
})
export class MainTrackPageComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() currentTrack:track;
  trackList: track[];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("currentTrack: ",  this.currentTrack)

  }

}
```

Comment: You're mixing up route navigation and embedding a child component here. What you've described isn't a parent-child relationship. That would be when you embed `app-child` in your `app-parent` and pass data via `@Input()` properties. You can pass data either by storing state in a service, or via the query string

Comment: https://medium.com/ableneo/how-to-pass-data-between-routed-components-in-angular-2306308d8255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are navigating components get destroyed . So In order to keep the passed data , stored . Create a service and store it there .
After navigating retrieve it from service

Answer (score 0):

You can create common data sharing service and include it your module's providers.
After you set data in parent component and you can get data after change routing in your child component.